# Is there any faker method which gives me the City Name of US based on the input character in C#?

Tags: c#, faker

I am working on some test scenarios and I want a method that takes a character as an input and returns me the name of the City, in US, starting with that character randomly? Is there any faker method available, any library for C#?

Thanks

Comment: welcome to StackOverflow. Unfortunately such questions don't fit the criteria for the questions that can be asked in this forum. It will be closed soon. Don't be offended. [Please read this helping post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need 2 things:

- A list of the names of cities in the US.
- A data structure called a "prefix tree" or "trie" (pronounced "try").

The prefix trie generalizes what you are doing (find things that match the first letter) to arbitrarily long prefixes (find things that match the first "n" characters).

A trie will allow you to type "Sea" and see names like "Seattle" and "Seatac".

You can find a list of cities from the US census Bureau. I don't have a link, but if you search around you can find one. You may have to process the data though to get what you want.

There is some data about tries here:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie

But if you search Google for Trie, or Trie C#, you can find existing resources.

That being said... if all you need is the exact problem you mentioned (type one letter, return a random match), you could just build an array of arrays, and populate that from the list of cities.

But... in most use cases the trie is more useful.

I would say... learn about tries, they are a cool data structure.

Then, if you really just need what you mentioned, just do an array of arrays (the first array is indexed by letter, the second array is a list of strings).

But learning about tries is totally worth your time.

If you really want to dive deep... try to be able to answer questions like:

1. How does, asymptotically, finding an item in a trie compare to finding an item in a hash table keyed by strings?
2. How, practically, do the two differ, and why?

Item #1 requires a decent understanding of algorithms.

Item #2 requires a bit of a deep dive into computer architecture.

Anyways... Ignore people when they say "this isn't a question that can be answered here"....

This is actually a question, that if you push your self on, could teach you an amazing amount about how computers work. Although it seems simple and strange and "like not a real question" on the surface.

So... that's the philosophical answer to your question.

The concrete answer to the exact question is:

1. Get a list of cities of the us.
2. Populate an array of arrays. Use cityName[0] - 'a' as the index to the outer array.
3. Get the inner array (from above), and grab a random index.

But that's the dumb answer... go learn about tries.

Wax on... wax off

Comment: Thanks, Scott for the answer. I did read about tries, got a really good understanding.